# how can i make D3 svg width same as the parent DIV

Tags: javascript, d3.js

so im very new to javascript world and and i went to d3 to make a line chart without the wihte background and the extra styling i dont need so  i used var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
its apply it to the svg but when i look at it in the inspector its way more and the chart line dont apppear fully any more becuase of the width here is my code

```
    import * as d3 from "d3";

    export function drawWeatherChart(dataa) {
        var container = document.getElementById('chartHold');
        var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
        var svgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svgElement.setAttribute("width", containerWidth);
        svgElement.setAttribute("height", "300");
        svgElement.setAttribute("id", "myChart");
        document.body.appendChild(svgElement);

        var svg = d3.select("#myChart");
        var height = +svg.attr("height");

        var minTemp = d3.min(dataa, function(d) {
            return +d.temp;
        });
        var maxTemp = d3.max(dataa, function(d) {
            return +d.temp;
        });

        var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date("2023-07-13"), new Date("2023-07-20")]).range([0, containerWidth]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minTemp, maxTemp]).range([height, 0]);

        dataa.sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(new Date(a.date), new Date(b.date)) || d3.descending(+a.temp, +b.temp);
        });

        var line = d3.line()
            .curve(d3.curveBasis)
            .x(function(d) {
                return x(new Date(d.date));
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y(+d.temp);
            });

        var path = svg.append("path")
            .datum(dataa)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#CEB398")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 500")
            .attr("d", line);

        var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

        path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
        return svgElement;

    }
```

i want the chart line to be fully taken the widht of the parent div and dont cut the chart line